# Output changes from DVI-D to DVI-A during boot process - any way to force Windows 7 to use DVI-D?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, blank-screen

I'm running Windows 7 through ATI HD5400 into HP2335 monitor.
I can manually switch betwen an analog DVI and a digital DVI source on this monitor.

Both BIOS and POST sequence work fine through the digital DVI (DVI-D)
However, while Windows is booting up, just after the Windows logo is first displayed, the screen goes blank when using a DVI-D (single link) cable.

However, I'm now using a DVI-I (dual link) cable and I've noticed a change.
When booting up and the screen goes blank (using digital DVI source on the monitor) I can switch the monitor to analog DVI and now get to see the desktop.

Is there any way to force Windows 7 or the ATI drivers to stick with the (better quality) DVI-D output/connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.komeil.com/2008/06/fixing-edid-dvi-monitors-no-signal.html

Adding an EDID_OVERRIDE registry entry for the monitor will most likely help. Too much trouble for one day though. I'll try this another time.

Comment: Windows 7 SP1 fixes the problem